# How to save image in jpg or png format in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

I am taking an image from UIImageView and this image I am creating programmatically.Now I want to save this image in jpg or png format in Resource folder.Can anyone know how can I save image in jpg or png format?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docs = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* path =  [docs stringByAppendingFormat:@"/image1.jpg"];

NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, .8)];
NSError *writeError = nil;

if(![imageData writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError]) {
    NSLog(@"%@: Error saving image: %@", [self class], [writeError localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: It is incorrect to check the error object before checking the return value of the call to `writeToFile:`. There is only guaranteed to be a valid object if the `BOOL` return is `NO`; if it is `YES`, the error is _not_ guaranteed to be `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Careful.  This line has a bug:

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 80)
```

If you look at the header, the compression quality should be a float between 0 (most lossy) and 1 (least compression)

```
UIKIT_EXTERN NSData *UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage *image, CGFloat compressionQuality);  // return image as JPEG. May return nil if image has no CGImageRef or invalid bitmap format. compression is 0(most)..1(least)
```